# Excel Formula Vlookup issue

Tags: excel, formula

I have 2 excel sheets ("sheet 1, sheet 2").

Sheet 1 and Sheet 2 have "product #" in column A and "price" in column C. I'm trying to write a formula that would allow Sheet 1 to lookup on sheet 2 if there is a Product # match In column A and if there is a product # match then to update on Sheet 1 Column C (Price) the product price from sheet 2. If there is no Match of product # from sheet 2 then to leave the price on sheet 1 alone.

I'm using this formula which returns a "0" on an error but I can't figure out how to modify it to leave price alone when there's no product # found.

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A2,updated!A:C,3,FALSE),0)
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only caveat here is that you need to write this formula in a new column, let's say in D2, because you can't overwrite your original price with the formula.

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A2,updated!A:C,3,FALSE),C2)
```

This says, "if A2 matches a value in Column A of the Updated Sheet, return the price from Column C of the updated sheet, unless there is an error, in which case, use the original price on Sheet 1 (`C2`).

Answer (score 0):

You want to use `INDEX/MATCH` for this:

Put the following formula in column `C` and populate down
    =IFERROR(IF(INDEX(Sheet2!B:B,MATCH(A2,Sheet2!A:A,0))=Sheet1!B2,B2,INDEX(Sheet2!B:B,MATCH(A2,Sheet2!A:A,0))),"")

The `MATCH` will find, the row on Sheet2 with the same Product ID, the `INDEX` will return the matching price. If it matches the one on Sheet1, the formula returns the value on Sheet1 in column `B`. If it doesn't it will return the price from Sheet2

Comment: my bad I think I was not so clear in the question... I need the price to remain on sheet 1 either way, so for example.. if the formula finds a product # on sheet 2 so it should fill in the price on sheet 1 and if it doesn't find the product # on sheet 2 it should leave the price for that product # on sheet one alone without changing anything. Thanks!